# dynamic array key in smarty

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I just want to know how to access an array in SMARTY that have generated index via smarty. I want to access it later.

Got something like this:

```
{if $smarty.get.{param_{$k.id}_{$p.num}} eq $key}
```

and I like to access `$smarty.get.(dynamic generated index)`

Tried a couple variations, but didn't have any luck.

Comment: working right now. When I get an answer I will accept it.

Comment: have you tried {$smarty.get[$your_var]} ?

Comment: @Alex with [] don't work. Also give an parse error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use variable for indexes, but you cannot build string the way you tried. Try to build a custom variable before:

```
{$myIndex = "param_{$k.id}_{$p.num}"}
{if $smarty.get.$myIndex eq $key}
    ...
```

This should work.

Comment: It is not giving an error, but var seems to be empty... Have to check if I have some sort of error in my code.

Comment: Works like a charm. Still want to know why when I build string outside it goes well, but when I want to build a string in actual index it fails.

Comment: I think it's by design. Your code just isn't valid Smarty syntax.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I used UnLoCo solution and tried to directly access array content (**without if statement**) with dynamic key and it works perfectly :

```
{$arr1["column_{$arr2.month}_price"]}
```

Comment: Confirmed, in PS 1.6.1.12 `{$myVar["keybase_{$i}"]}` works.

Answer (score 0):

This will work also

```
{if $smarty.get["param_{$k.id}_{$p.num}"] eq $key}
  ...
```